# how can i output all designed data set from one lib

Tags: sas, sas-macro

develop a macro that will access a library called "test" and pull 100 records from the tables as long as the table name started with "math_"
please offer as much detail as you can.
thank you

Comment: Looks like homework, what have you tried so far. Please remember to follow the guidelines here when asking a question. [ask]

Comment: Why would you need a macro for this?

Comment: Hi - welcome to Stack Overflow.  You might want to read [ask] and the [help]; Stack Overflow is a question and answer site that expects users to post questions about *code they have written* or *code they are writing*, that include a minimally complete example of the code and any data needed to reproduce any issue you're having.  While it's okay to ask "how do I do X", you still should be able to show at least something, your ideas for how to approach it or what you've tried that didn't work.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey Guys, sorry i did not look howtoask details. here is my thoughts. i thought I can use proc contents data=test._all_ to pull out all dataset in lib test, but  don't know how to process next step to pull out all dataset starts with math_ and first 100 records. or I have to use proc SQL obs to do one more thing

Comment: Look up the sashelp.vtable data set and see what it contains.

Comment: What does "to pull 100 records" mean for you? Copy them to a new dataset? Print them? Remove them from the original dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that does what you want.
You didn´t say what to do with the 100 pulled observations, so I just put them all together in one dataset. This will only work if the datasets have the same varables and formats.

```
*Get names of tables in library;
ods output Members=Tables;
proc datasets library=test memtype=data;
run;
quit;

*Store tablenames that start with math as macrovariables;
data _null_;*add this if on viya: / single=yes;
    set tables end=last;
    retain Num_tables 0;
    if find(upcase(name),"MATH_") eq 1 then do;
        call symputx("table"||strip(_N_),name,"G");
        Num_tables=Num_tables+1;
        end;
    if last then
    call symputx("Num_tables",Num_tables,"G");
run;

*create target dataset;
data math100;run;

*Iterate over datasets;
%macro get_math_100();
    %do i=1 %to &Num_tables.;
        data math100;
            set math100 test.&&table&i.. (obs=100) ;
        run;
    %end;
%mend;

%get_math_100();
```